# dynamically allocated 2D array Runtime error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

I was trying to solve this problem but this message appeared after finishing the first test case loop, and when i uploaded it to codeforces it gets a Run time error verdict!

Given 2D Array of integers of size N*N. Print the sum of the perfect square numbers.

For example, 25, 16, 36 and 9 are perfect square numbers. But 35, 17, 23 and 11 are not.

Input
Your input consists of T (1 ≤ T ≤ 10^2) test cases. Each test case contains only 1 integers N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^2). N lines follow each line contains N space separated integers (1 ≤ Nij ≤ 10^2).

Output
For each test case print a single integer in a single line, the required sum.

Example input

```
2
2
9 97
8 56
3
1 18 6
16 42 100
25 16 17
```

output:

```
9
158
```

Code:

```
void main()
{
int n, x, **z, m, i, j, q, p, sum;
float y;

scanf("%d", &x);
for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    z = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        z[j] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for (p = 0; p < n; p++)
        for (q = 0; q < n; q++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &z[p][q]);
            m = sqrt(z[p][q]);
            y = sqrt(z[p][q]) - m;
            if ((y) == 0)
                sum += z[p][q];
        }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        free(z[i]);
    free(z);
}
return;}
```

[image of message i get when i debug on VSc++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOGlk.png)

Update: free(z[i]) was edited to be free(z[j])

Update: thanks for jpw it worked well in VS, but this time resulted in compilation error in Codeforces rather than Runtime error.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: What compilation error do you get?

Comment: Can't compile file:
program.cpp(25) : error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
it could be 'long double sqrt(long double)', or float sqrt(float)' ,or 'double sqrt(double)'

        while trying to match the argument list '(int)'

Comment: what about `int value; scanf("%d", &value); z[p][q] = value; m = (int)sqrt((double)value); if ( m*m == value) { sum += value;}`?

Comment: @Bob__ WOW!! .. it worked like a magic :D 
I don't know why, but it worked. I'm more than thankful :) 

Could you please explain it for me. I'd be grateful

Comment: Apparently the C++ compiler you are using can't decide which of the three overloaded `sqrt` function should use. You are passing an `int` and in my snippet I explicity casted it to a `float` so it can choose. Note that using a C compiler and the right includes (like in ideone online compiler) this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a simple typo...

`free(z[i]);` at the end should be `free(z[j]);`

Changing that makes it run fine in [ideone](https://ideone.com/wtAFre)

Comment: Thank you so much :) 
I don't know how I could miss this!
thanks again :)

edit: and your edit was perfect.

Comment: it worked well in VS, but this time resulted in compilation error in Codeforces rather than Runtime error

Comment: @MohamedFathy I can't tell you why that is. Are you including the relevant headers and so forth?